# Pentaho Business Intelligence

Tags: pentaho, pentaho-cde

Is there anywhere i can get like a tutorial to watch and build out a full dashboard or different charts? I have already watched a few tutorials but still didn't get the hang of it. Or is there anywhere i can download a demo dashboard or report to set up on my side?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about the official http://www.pentaho.com/service/custom-dashboards.

And if you need something specific about CDE, browse the web site of the author http://www.webdetails.pt/. Or send them a mail, Perdo Alves will answer you with pleasure.